Bundle identifier required during dotnet publish
I have a MAUI project that I have published before and have made changes that I need to publish. When I try to build the iOS .ipa using the dotnet publish command I am getting the following warnings and error:
warning : Supported iPhone orientations have not been set
error : A bundle identifier is required. Either add an 'ApplicationId' property in the project file, or add a 'CFBundleIdentifier' entry in the project's Info.plist file.
I have updated my Xcode and verified that I can build the app in release mode in my IDE. Both the iPhone orientations and Bundle Identifier are set in the info.plist. The only change I have made to the info.plist file since the last successful publish is the version number.
Any suggestions for resolving this issue is appreciated.

You can check if the version settings in the project‘s .csproj file matchs the version in the info.plist file. The <ApplicationDisplayVersion> in the csproj file matches the Version in the info.plist file, and the <ApplicationVersion> matches the Build.

I was not in the correct project directory when attempting the publish command. Disregard this question.
